# If $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are two symmetrical matrices with same eigenvectors then AB =BA.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following statement 
"If $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are two symmetrical matrices with same eigenvectors then $AB = BA$." (#)

I know that $AB = BA$ => same eigenvectors is a false statement because we can easily find a counterexample. But what's with this (#) statement?
A proof is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** There exists orthogonal matrix $P$ and diagonal $D_1, D_2$ such that 
$$A=PD_1P^T\\B=PD_2P^T$$

*Note* The claim still holds if $A,B$ are diagonalisable,  $A=PD_1P^{-1}\\B=PD_2P^{-1}$. Symmetric is only used to deduce that the matrices are (orthogonally) diagonalisable.

Comment: This is true if and only if $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are symmetric.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera $(#)$ gives that $A,B$ are symmetrical.

Comment: Oops, how on earth did I miss that? Apologies for the irrelevant comment. If $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are not diagonalisable, they still commute if they have the same invariant subspaces, but  it's not sufficient for them merely to have the same set of generalised eigenvectors.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera No worry... Actually symmetric is more than one needs, we only need to know they are both diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

If they are symmetrical, they can be diagonalized in an orthonormal eigenvector basis but if they share the same eigenvectors then the basis is the same for both.

Take  $v$ from the eigenvector basis, suppose its eigenvalue is $\lambda$ for $A$ and $\mu$ for $B$. then $ABv=A\mu v= \lambda \mu v$ and $BAv=B\lambda v=\mu \lambda v$ which shows that they commute for every vector in a basis of the space, therefore they commute in the whole space.